# libjingle for Facebook video chat

Tags: ios5

As We know that xmpp framework can be used both for facebook and gmail text chat. I found that libjingle is used to video chat for gmail contacts. Can we use the libjingle for Facebook video chat too?

Please share your views.

Thanks
Sanjay

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit of a mischaracterization of libjingle. The main purpose of libjingle is to set up a peer to peer tunnel between two users of a particular xmpp server. It can set up this tunnel across most firewalls and VPNs. The XMPP side of libjingle can be used to exchange messages, presence updates, etc, but there are much lighter weight frameworks that let you do this.

Google video chat is implemented through libjingle, but the video stuff is all on Google's side. Let me emphasize: libjingle is not a video chat library. If you wanted to create a video chat for your users with Google accounts, you would need to implement all the video encoding, decoding, etc yourself. libjingle simply lets you leverage Google's infrastructure to set up a direct TCP connection between users.

This also applies to Facebook video chat, with the added complexity that libjingle works out of the box with Google accounts. From last I heard, Facebook's XMPP servers do not support IQ stanzas, which are necessary for setting up a Jingle tunnel.